# How to update the Entity Framework auto-generated code for the results of a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

What I am trying to achieve is to get the auto-generated code to update for the results of a stored procedure.

What I have done so far is:

1. Modified the stored procedures in my development database
2. In Visual Studio:

   2.1 Made sure the connection string is set in the Server Explorer

   2.2 Right clicked on the EDMX diagram and selected Update Model from database. The update wizard is displayed. I don't add anything, and I check the stored procedure is in the list. After this I click the Finish button.
3. I then get the "Running this text template can potentially harm your computer" message twice, which I click OK on.
4. Save the changes
5. Build the DLL
6. Right click on the tt (not the context one) under the EDMX and select run custom tool.  I get the same security message as above, so click ok.

Everything seems to be running ok, and there are no obvious errors.

I have also tried the Transform All T4 Templates under the build menu.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2014. The Entity Framework runtime version is 4.0.30319.

I have had a look in the EDMX xml file and there is an entry for the `FunctionImportMapping` for the stored procedure and the class it will create.

If it makes any difference when I try to connect to the database using the SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio, it displays the SQL Server 2012 login, if I click connect it displays the "An incompatible SQL Server version was detected".  That can be cured by installing the latest version of SSDT for Visual Studio 2013.

I am new to Entity Framework, so any help will be appreciated.

How do I get the class to update, or is it that I am overthinking the issue and have to update it manually?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the logs files on the SQL Server and Event Viewer to see if you get more details on the error.  When did issue start occurring or you always had issue?  there was a change from VS 2012 to VS 2013 where default encoding went from UTF-8 to Unicode.  I'm wondering if  this is related to your issue.  I had lots of problems 4 years ago trying to use 2013 and still run UTF-8.  Don't remember how I solved issue.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for the reply.  The logs unfortunately didn't come up with anything.  I have managed to cure the error by installing the SSDT for Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution which seems to have done the trick:

1. Open the EDMX diagram
2. Update the model from the database
3. Right click on the diagram and select Model Browser from the menu
4. Expand the Function Imports folder
5. Find the stored procedure that has been modified.
6. Double click on it and the Edit Function Import form will be displayed
7. Click Get Column Information
8. Ensure the correct complex type is selected, and click update.
9. Click OK

The new columns should now be added to the auto-generated code.